# How to make browsers theme color with css

Tags: html, css

How to use this code in an CSS file?

`<meta name="theme-color" content="#38bb38">
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#38bb38">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#38bb38">`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. These meta tags are not used for editing the style of web pages and must instead be placed in the  of webpages.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- icon in the highest resolution we need it for -->
<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="icon.png">

<!-- reuse same icon for Safari -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="ios-icon.png">

<!-- multiple icons for IE -->
<meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="icon_largetile.png">
```

link:-https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/browser-customization/

Comment: Did you mean to post this to another question? It has nothing to do with this one.